# Ajax creates form based on value but will not submit

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms, submit

Ok so here is the scenario : 
The app is built with Ajax requesting How many services do we need ? ( I don't validate anything for this purpose but I should )

Say we give five as an input the form return with 5 boxes and a submit button

```
<script>
    function test(){
        var num = $('#numServ').val();
        var form = "";

        form += "<form name='form2' id='services' method='POST' action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>'>";
        for(m=0;m<num;m++){
            // alert("<br>Voice le param"+m);
            form += "<br><input type='text' name='services"+m+"' value=''>";
        }
        form += "<input type='submit' name='services' id='btnServices' value='SERVICES'>";

        form += "</form>";
        alert(form);
        $('#generated').append(form)
    }
</script>
```

This part works ... but when I try to submit the form usin Ajax which the function for this Ajax call was place in the document.ready function it jst doesn't work.

```
$('#form2').submit(function(){
    alert("Form Submitted");

    /*
    THE WHOLE CODE COMMENTED OUT IT STILL WON'T WORK
    var result = $(this).serialize();

    alert(result);
    $.ajax({
        url:"./content.php",
        data: result, 
        type: "POST",
        // cache:false,
        dataType:"html",
        success: function(data,jqXHR){$('body').append(data);},
        error: function(){alert('Check Ajax request');},
        complete:function(){alert("Ajax complete");}
    });
    */

    return false;
});
```

I have been at it for days now. 
Any other forms that are not built using jquery will work using this method as the form is already loaded on the page and not beeing made by ajax on the fly.

I believe my issue lies with Ajax making the form after the page has been loaded ... even though my Ajax call to sumit the form is in the head inside the document.ready function.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is listening for a submit event on an element with in ID of `form2` but your form is named `services`.

Also, it looks like you are building the form dynamically, so the submit event may not fire because the jQuery loads before the form exists.

If this is the case, try using `$(#[ID of parent element that exists on page load]).on('submit', function() {...});`

### Update

jQuery .on() [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) has lots of good info. The short version is that events "bubble" up the DOM. By adding the listener to an element that exists on page load, it can catch events that happen to it's children.

It looks like you are appending the form to an element with an `ID` of "generated"... if this element exists on page load then the following should work:

```
$('#generated').on('submit', function() {
    alert("Form Submitted");

    var result = $(this).serialize();

    alert(result);

    $.ajax({
        url:"./content.php",
        data: result, 
        type: "POST",
        // cache:false,
        dataType:"html",
        success: function(data,jqXHR){$('body').append(data);},
        error: function(){alert('Check Ajax request');},
        complete:function(){alert("Ajax complete");}*/
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: thats exactly what i think is happening .... can you elaborate a little more on this function `$(#[ID of parent element that exists on page load]).on('submit', function() {...});`

Comment: @hayonj I have updated my answer with some more info and included your original code.

Comment: that does work ! so if i understand correctly, I cannot submit a form with Ajax unless the container in this case a DIV was loaded on the page load     Also what i weird is the `$('#generated').on('submit', function() {` instead of using the actual ID of the form instead.

Comment: It's more broad then just submitting a form. This is true for any event you want to listen for in the DOM (like `submit`, `click`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery is looking for a form with `id='form2'` but your form creation function is setting `id='services'`  So the jQuery isn't running because it isn't matching anything.

change:

```
$('#form2').submit(function(){
```

to:

```
$('#services').submit(function(){
```